# gamma distribution lower limit in R

Tags: r, threshold, gamma-distribution, fitdistrplus

I would like to fit a gamma distribution to a dataset made of 338 elements, **with a fixed low threshold** (I'm using R).
To represent the low limit I thought to use a gamma with three parameters, adding the location. Here's my code:

```
library(FAdist)
library(fitdistrplus)
fit <- fitdist(mydata,"gamma3",start=list(1,1,mythreshold))
```

Everytime i run the code, I got the same error:

```
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): non-finite finite-difference value [3]>
Error in fitdist(Hs, "gamma3", start = list(1, 1, 3)) : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
```

So I tried to change the starting values, using the ones obtained by the fit of the gamma with two parameters, which gave this result:

```
fit <- fitdist(mydata,"gamma")
fit
Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
       estimate Std. Error
shape 21.417503  1.6348313
rate   5.352422  0.4133735
```

But it still doesn't work..I would understand it if even the gamma with two parameters didn't work, but this is not the case and I can't give myself an explanation. Moreover, the QQ-plot and the ecdf for the gamma with two parameters are not so good...but if i fit the distribution on the original dataset scaled with respect to the low threshold the fit looks perfect:

```
fit <- fitdist(mydata-mythreshold,"gamma")
fit
Fitting of the distribution ' gamma ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters:
      estimate Std. Error
shape 1.059540 0.07212832
rate  1.058007 0.09117620
```

But then I don't know if it is correct to do like that...the parameters are very different and I need them to calculate the return periods related to my data ! that's why I thought about the gamma with the location parameter.

p.s. i did not attach the data because they are too many, but i can report the summary of them:

```
 summary(mydata)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  3.003   3.282   3.753   4.001   4.444   8.087
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up a reproducible example;

```
library(FAdist); library(fitdistrplus)
set.seed(101)
x <- rgamma3(1000,shape=1,scale=1,thres=1)
```

For values of the threshold parameter greater than the minimum value in the data set the likelihood is infinite (since these values are supposed to be impossible/have a value of zero under the truncated distribution).  We can make things work by setting an upper bound for this parameter:

```
fitdist(x,dgamma3,start=list(shape=1,scale=1,thres=0.5),
        upper=c(Inf,Inf,min(x)))
## Fitting of the distribution ' gamma3 ' by maximum likelihood 
## Parameters:
##        estimate Std. Error
## shape 0.9321949         NA
## scale 1.0586079         NA
## thres 1.0000012         NA
```

Note (1) under maximum likelihood this kind of threshold parameter will always end up at the largest value it can take (i.e., the minimum value in the data set); (2) the standard errors are `NA` because Wald standard errors can't be computed when the parameters hit a boundary.

Alternatively you can fix the threshold parameter by defining wrapper function:

```
dgconstr <- function(x,shape,scale,...) {
    dgamma3(x,shape,scale,thres=0.5,...)
}
pgconstr <- function(...) {
    pgamma3(...,thres=0.5)
}

fitdist(x,dgconstr,start=list(shape=1,scale=1))
```

Comment: Thank you so much Ben! I got it and it definitively worked.